# httpd-2.2.17 ignores Directory, Location directives, doesn't output to access log

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

Very strange issue at work.

I have a very basic Apache configuration. Has a `DocumentRoot`, `<Directory ...>` section within which there is an `Options +Indexes` directive that isn't being honoured (I just get a 404 error when trying to access the directory listing).

The Apache I've build is set to be installed in `/usr/local/apache22` however I've got a copy in a different path and am calling it with:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/apache22/lib /tmp/apache22/bin/httpd -f /tmp/test.conf
```

The configuration gets loaded successfully but doesn't honour the `Directory`, `Location`, or `Option Indexes` directives. In addition an error log is correctly being written to when requesting a bad URL, however the access log is NOT being written to when accessing a good URL.

A friend has tried the same configuration on a different machine using a differently compiled web server and it functions fine. So the configuration is not at fault. I'm wondering if perhaps Apache silently fails when not located in its destined directory...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the right answer so I'll leave this question open for some time to see if there's a better one.

I rsync'd the entire build across to another server, placed it in the path it was built for, and it ran just as expected using the same config that was causing me grief earlier.

It makes me wonder why Apache doesn't complain or error when located in a different path to that for which it was built.. it just silently fails to operate as expected.